# overflow hidden problem in react js (front-end)

Tags: css, frontend

[[image: you can see last link is out of sight]] I am creating a Mobile Menu in React Js;

```
const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

 // when i toggle menuOpen , **my sidebar** (mobile Menu) show/hides;

 if (menuOpen) {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = "initial";
  }
```

this above code stops scrolling when menu is open.

everything is working file. **but now when i added sub menus and sub sub menus,
the menu items goes out of screen.**

when i use overflow scroll on sidebar(mobile menu sidebar element) it does not work(scroll).

**So is there any rule that child elements cannot scroll if parent element's overflow hidden.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a max-height to the container that surrounds the navigation and then set it to show the scrollbar, this will ensure the contaienr doesn't extend off screen as you're experiencing.

```
.your-container {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```